# Characters in Japanese are not decoded properly

Tags: decode, python-3.4, beautifulsoup

I am currently crawling some website in Japanese using BeautifulSoup4.
I have some problem decoding Japanese characters. Only '~' and 'ー' are returned as square shape character. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? The website is encoded in 'utf-8'.

Here is my code for parsing:

```
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resonse.text, 'html.parser')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the encoding of the site you are looking at, and also have a look at the BeautifulSoup.prettify function to change the encoding.

Comment: @SeanF The website is encoded in utf-8 and I am pretty sure that html.parser uses utf-8 as a default value.